# How to preserve ui-grid selection after changing data source?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

As I understand, ui-grid uses the `primaryKey` grid option to preserve your selection across updates, but this simple plunker shows this is not true:

http://plnkr.co/edit/WYXeQShHWKDYDs4MIZnP?p=preview

Steps to repro:

1. Click a row to select it
2. Click "click me to reset the data source". This will reset the data source (to a data source that contains exactly the same data as before).
3. Your selection is now gone.

The initial data source is:

```
data: [
  { id: "item1" },
  { id: "item2" }
],
```

With

```
primaryKey: 'id',
```

When you click on the button, here is the handler:

```
  $scope.resetDataSource = function()
  {
    $scope.gridOptions.data = [  { id: "item1" }, { id: "item2" } ];
    $scope.$apply();
  };
```

Removing the `$scope.gridOptions.data =` line will preserve the selection just fine.

The new data source is exactly the same (contents) as the old.

What can I do to preserve selection after assigning a new data source?

Comment: use `angular.copy` and store that ui-grid configuration in some variable.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How will copying anything help?

Comment: @tenfour where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use option `restoreSelection`

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.saveState.service:uiGridSaveStateService